# R, Convert Dataset to mlogit(/mnlogit) long-format

Tags: r, reshape, mlogit

I would like to use the `R` `mlogit` package. The documentation (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/vignettes/mlogit.pdf) is well written, but I still have a question.

Suppose I have a dataset composed of three categorical variables: `mode`, `age`, `cost`. `mode` has three levels (`mode1`, `mode2`, `mode3`), and the other two variables have two levels (`age1`, `age2` and `cost1`, `cost2`).

Basically, it is in the following form:

```
R> head(df)
  mode   age   cost
1 mode2  age1  cost2
2 mode1  age1  cost2
3 mode1  age2  cost1
4 mode3  age1  cost1
```

With the command `mlogitSample <- mlogit.data(df, choice = "mode", shape = "wide")` I am able to "convert" this dataset to the `mlogit` format: every row is expanded into three rows (corresponding to the three different response categories), with the `mode` column converted to a sequence of `TRUE` or `FALSE`. This is perfect for using `mlogit`; however, I think it is also why I obtain the error `Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[8,8] = 0`, given that I have multiple rows which are no more independent.

Since I know that it is possible to apply the multinomial logit method to my case, I would like to know how I can do it with this package. To a similar aim, the function `multinom` of package `nnet` works fine, but it does not fit the same model I have in mind: I would like to fit the model $\log(\pi_j(x)) = \alpha_j + \beta\cdot x$, with an intercept $\alpha_j$ varying for each mode category $j$, and a vector of constant coefficients $\beta$).

Comment: 1) Please post a reproducible sample dataset showing this error.  2) How do you "know" it works? What other software or pencil+paper method succeeded?

Comment: 1) Post a reproducible example 2) Tell us your package versions, upgrade to the latest, open a clean R session, reverify you still see your issue. Mine are *mlogit 0.2.4 (maxLik 1.2.0) / mnlogit 1.1.1* 3) Try also ***mnlogit*** package.